# typescript typing encapsulation

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, encapsulation

In the following example, I seek to describe a complex typescript type that I want to use later `FinalType`. The thing is, due to it's complexity, this type required the declaration of intermediary types that are polluting the page `IntermediaryType`/`IntermediaryType2`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdsCAnAthAJgSwIZJAFXGgF4oBvAKCinQgGNMBnTANwgGkIQAuKYJAK4QANFSgoBwbInSceUABRhc2FI17Y4IAJRRiAPigsA9pnSiAvlAA+5MbQbM2c3gDNsAG0YixEqTLkAfjdPb0sKCkwEZHc6aHhEVAwcPEJIACY7aldjY2CoRn4ogHNRagAjXHzy3I8ITXCKUEgoADEozzSSWGikrFwCIigAMh7EtH7UonSAbgi6YzhCtty9RWUkVV52uE6iXQNyCwjW3IVKagcmVg4uXn4hMvFJaQwXRQPDMgtLbRmgA)

```
type IntermediaryType = {
  decisiveKey: true,
  mutatedKey: (params: any) => void,
} | {
  decisiveKey: false,
  mutatedKey?: false,
}

interface IntermediaryType2 {
  foo?: string,
  bar?: boolean,
}

type FinalType = IntermediaryType & IntermediaryType2;

const Foo = (param: FinalType) => {}

Foo({
  decisiveKey: true,
  mutatedKey: () => {},
});
```

---

My question is, is there any way to makes the intermediary types unreachable, and only allow the use of `FinalType` ?

---

I've seen that you can enclosure some part of the code using **brackets** like :

```
{
  type IntermediaryType = {
    decisiveKey: true,
    mutatedKey: (params: any) => void,
  } | {
    decisiveKey: false,
    mutatedKey?: false,
  }

  interface IntermediaryType2 {
    foo?: string,
    bar?: boolean,
  }

  type FinalType = IntermediaryType & IntermediaryType2;
}

const Foo = (param: FinalType) => {}

Foo({
  decisiveKey: true,
  mutatedKey: () => {},
});
```

But then I obviously can't access `FinalType`. I've tried to use `return` or `export` but none works.

The ideal would be something like :

```
type FinalType = {
  type IntermediaryType = {
    decisiveKey: true,
    mutatedKey: (params: any) => void,
  } | {
    decisiveKey: false,
    mutatedKey?: false,
  }

  interface IntermediaryType2 {
    foo?: string,
    bar?: boolean,
  }

  return IntermediaryType & IntermediaryType2;
}

const Foo = (param: FinalType) => {}

Foo({
  decisiveKey: true,
  mutatedKey: () => {},
});
```

---

Any leads ?

---

---

Using @Aluan Haddad answer, for now the best I can achieve is :

```
namespace _ {
    type IntermediaryType = {
        decisiveKey: true,
        mutatedKey: (params: any) => void,
    } | {
        decisiveKey: false,
        mutatedKey?: false,
    }

    interface IntermediaryType2 {
        foo?: string,
        bar?: boolean,
    }

    export type FinalType = IntermediaryType & IntermediaryType2;
}; type FinalType = _.FinalType;

const Foo = (param: FinalType) => {}

Foo({
  decisiveKey: true,
  mutatedKey: () => {},
});
```

I would love to add some syntax sugar on it!

Comment: I think you should organize your architecture via different files, and on this case, export only the FinalType. By this way, you will have a file with all intermediary types and your final type, however, only the final type could be used in an external file.

Comment: It's an architecture advice that is good 90% of the time. But when you type privates methods that are using slightly modified existing types ; I hardly see the value of putting in in an external file.

Answer (score 2):

What your are literally trying to do, introducing arbitrary scopes for types, can be accomplished via a *TypeScript* namespace.

```
declare namespace myNamespace {
  type IntermediaryType = {
    decisiveKey: true,
    mutatedKey: (params: any) => void,
  } | {
    decisiveKey: false,
    mutatedKey?: false,
  }

  interface IntermediaryType2 {
    foo?: string,
    bar?: boolean,
  }

  export type FinalType = IntermediaryType & IntermediaryType2;
}

const Foo = (param: myNamespace.FinalType) => {}

Foo({
  decisiveKey: true,
  mutatedKey: () => {},
});
```

However, if you are writing modern code, and therefore using modules, namespaces should almost always be avoided. Fortunately, if you're are using modules the solution is even simpler; don't export the intermediate types.

```
type IntermediaryType = {
  decisiveKey: true,
  mutatedKey: (params: any) => void,
} | {
  decisiveKey: false,
  mutatedKey?: false,
}

interface IntermediaryType2 {
  foo?: string,
  bar?: boolean,
}

export type FinalType = IntermediaryType & IntermediaryType2;

export const Foo = (param: FinalType) => {}

Foo({
  decisiveKey: true,
  mutatedKey: () => {},
});
```

Comment: The namespace would do the trick, but still it's not convenient to use it. Re-declaring the type in addition would make it `type FinalType = namespace.FinalType;`. About the second proposal, in the local file scope, the export doesn't solve anything. Thanks for your answer

Comment: If it is all for scoping within a single file, then namespaces are appropriate, even within a module. It's a tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your preface

> due to it's complexity, this type required the declaration of intermediary types

this compiles

```
type FinalType = (
  | {
      decisiveKey: true;
      mutatedKey: (params: any) => void;
    }
  | {
      decisiveKey: false;
      mutatedKey?: false;
    }
) & {
  foo?: string;
  bar?: boolean;
};

const Foo = (param: FinalType) => {};

Foo({
  decisiveKey: true,
  mutatedKey: () => {}
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So your solution is to suppress `type` and `interface` keywords. Could be a soluce for some cases. But seems a bit complex if applied to huge and deep types

Comment: To expose everything required to build everything exposed (a type in your case) is in TypeScript nature. If you want to not expose any intermediate type you need to use native types only.